# Group and sum in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am developing an app which is a card game. Each card is stored in a table (cards) and has a certain number of points. If a user wins a card he earns the points of this card. In this case a record is saved in the user_card table holding `card_id`, `user_id` and `success = true` (if he loses the card it is `success = false`).

**card.rb**

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cards
  has_many :users, through: :user_cards
end
```

**user_card.rb**

```
class UserCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :card
end
```

What I want to do now is to create a leaderboard. Therefore I need to:

1. Group all user_cards where success = true by user_id
2. Sum all points (which are stored in the card table) for successful user_cards by user
3. Display username (from user table) and sum of points for this user

I tried some approaches like group_by(&:something), joins etc. However, I cannot make it work. I don't have problems when I have to group and sum stuff from a single table. However, I don't know how to get the username from the one and the points from the other table summed up based on the user_card table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users = User.joins(:cards).
             select(:username, 'sum(cards.score) as score').
             where(user_cards: {success: true}).
             group(:id).
             order('score desc')
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User username: 'bob'>]>

users.first.username
#=> "bob"

users.first.score
#=> 15
```

Comment: True this works. I realized that I missed important information in my original post: everytime a user plays a card this is stored in user_card. The table holds a boolean called "success" - if a user wins this is "true" else it is "false". I updated my original post.

Comment: Awesome! Your update works! Last question: how can I now order this descending by the sum of score? (In the leaderboard I want a list with all users and points in descending order)

Comment: That's it! You saved me a lot of time! Thanks!